# Powershell Script to monitoring status and send email results

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a lot of websites to monitor their up/down status, possible errors, ping and the other things that I managed to get with a script. My idea is the following: This script will run with task scheduler, get the results and send us (from the SQA publications) an email. So, I managed to create the script with success, he gets all I need and generates a html file in the C: drive. My problem is that after I get the result the function which sends the email isn't sending the email. I don't get any error messages, debug is fine, SMTP and all configurations are correct. But it won't send the email with the html file attached!

The code is this:

```
$URLListFile = "C:\URLList.txt"  
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
  $Result = @() 


  Foreach($Uri in $URLList) { 
  $time = try{ 
  $request = $null 

  $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri } 
  $result1.TotalMilliSeconds 
  }  
  catch 
  { 

   $request = $_.Exception.Response 
   $time = -1 
  }   
  $result += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
  Time = Get-Date; 
  Uri = $uri; 
  StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode; 
  StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription; 
  ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength; 
  TimeTaken =  $time;  
  } 

} 

if($result -ne $null) 
{ 
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>Website Report Status</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Report Status </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B> Code </B></TD><TD><B> Status </B></TD><TD><B> Duration </B></TD><TD><B> MS (Ping) </B></TD</TR>" 
    Foreach($Entry in $Result) 
    { 
        if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200") 
        { 
           $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
        } 
        $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>" 
    } 
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
} 

$Outputreport | out-file C:\URLReport.htm 
Invoke-Expression C:\URLReport.htm   


$EmailFrom = "noreply@domain.com"
$EmailTo = "destinyemail@domain.com"
$EmailSubject = "URL Report"
$emailbody = " body message "
$SMTPServer = "smtpserver.company.com"

$emailattachment = "C:\URLReport.htm"

function send_email {
$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
$mailmessage.from = ($emailfrom)
$mailmessage.To.add($emailto)
$mailmessage.Subject = $emailsubject
$mailmessage.Body = $emailbody

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($emailattachment, 'html')
  $mailmessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)


$mailmessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.Send($mailmessage)
}
```

**EDIT4:** > ($SmtpServer, 587) Beeing " 587 " the port that our smtp server uses.

Comment: You need to explain "doesn't send". For starters, you aren't calling `send_email`, which is a bit of an impediment to sending the email. Any error messages? Also, there are products (some free, some not free) that perform website monitoring. Why not use one of those, instead of rolling your own?

Comment: have you tried using the existing Send-MailMessage ?

Comment: It just won't send the email, it executes the first part of the script and it seems like it won't execute the " emailing " part. About the " send_email " I corrected, was missing a part of the script. The thing is, my company does not uses others softwares and they won't pay for the license of this softwares. Besides that, my boss asked me to write this one and I'm using it as a way to keep learning powershell.

Comment: The guy that answered me used Send-MailMessage and worked perfectly, thank you Jimbo fo your help too :)

Comment: "my company does not uses others softwares and they won't pay for the license of this softwares" - then your company has some major issues. Don't build something like this if it can be bought (or even better, there's a free one available somewhere - there almost certainly is in this case), because ultimately it'll probably be better and cheaper than using an employee's time. But that's kind of irrelevant here, has Powershell is a component of Windows - so as long as you're paying for your Windows licenses, you're set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using Powershell v3, you should be using `Send-MailMessage` instead of dealing with `System.Net`.

```
$URLListFile = "C:\URLList.txt"  
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
  $Result = @() 


  Foreach($Uri in $URLList) { 
  $time = try{ 
  $request = $null 

  $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri } 
  $result1.TotalMilliSeconds 
  }  
  catch 
  { 

   $request = $_.Exception.Response 
   $time = -1 
  }   
  $result += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
  Time = Get-Date; 
  Uri = $uri; 
  StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode; 
  StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription; 
  ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength; 
  TimeTaken =  $time;  
  } 

} 

if($result -ne $null) 
{ 
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>Website Report Status</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Report Status </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B> Code </B></TD><TD><B> Status </B></TD><TD><B> Duration </B></TD><TD><B> MS (Ping) </B></TD</TR>" 
    Foreach($Entry in $Result) 
    { 
        if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200") 
        { 
           $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
        } 
        $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>" 
    } 
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
} 

$Outputreport | out-file C:\URLReport.htm 
Invoke-Item C:\URLReport.htm   

$EmailFrom = "noreply@domain.com"
$EmailTo = "destinyemail@domain.com"
$EmailSubject = "URL Report"
$emailbody = " body message "
$SMTPServer = "smtpserver.company.com"

$emailattachment = "C:\URLReport.htm"

Send-MailMessage -Port 587 -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Attachments $emailattachment -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $emailbody -Bodyashtml;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I didn't know about that " Send-MailMessage " function. You, sir, just helped me a lot. Really thank you ! :)