# I am trying to create a script in powershell that will send a email based off of results of a command and have no idea where to start

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

This is all in powershell 4.0
We currently have this script that we manually run once a week that tells us all the users on the network who's password will expire in <=7 days.

```
#get max password age policy
$maxPwdAge=(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days

#expiring in 7 days
$7days=(get-date).AddDays(7-$maxPwdAge).ToShortDateString()

Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False - and PasswordLastSet -gt 0} –Properties * | where {($_.PasswordLastSet).ToShortDateString() -le $7days} | Select-Object -Property "Displayname"
```

This displays a list of names when run. I then want to take the list of names it generates, add the string "@example.com" to have a string "user.name@example.com"

I thien want to send an email to that email address

```
$EmailFrom = "noreply@domain.com" 

$EmailTo = "destinyemail@domain.com"
```

The EmailTo needs to change for each person. It could even be emailed to all the users the above outputs in one email.

```
$EmailSubject = "PasswordExpiring"
$emailbody = " body message "
$SMTPServer = "smtpserver.company.com"


Send-MailMessage -Port 587 -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Attachments $emailattachment -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $emailbody -Bodyashtml;
```

Comment: maybe the last few lines of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17456077/2152082) can help?

Comment: begin here "Powershell Send-MailMessage" https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have edited the post to include the last few lines. I am confused how to write something that will change the email destination based on the usernames the first part retrieves?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Displayname` format is "FirstName LastName" (e.g. "Jon Doe") and email address format is "FirstName.LastName@example.com":

```
$displayNames = Get-ADUser ...

foreach ($sdisplayName in $displayNames ) { 
    $Parts = $sdisplayName -split ' '
    $EmailTo = $Parts[0] + '.' + $Parts[-1]
    Send-MailMessage -To $EmailTo ...
}
```

Comment: I Keep getting the error that "an invalid character was found in the mail header: '@'. "

Comment: IIRC, `displayName` attribute in AD may include middle initial. Updated my code to handle such cases.